# Iteration with for loop

Tags: python

I've gotten to the point where I can calculate total meal costs given a range of tipping percentages:

```
def total_cost(price,tax,tip):

    bill = price+(price*tax)+((price+(price*tax))*tip)
    return bill

for tip in range(15,30,5): 

    cost = total_cost(20, 0.1350, tip/100.)  
    print(cost)
```

I'm stumped when mixing multiple variables from the below question:

Below you will find a dictionary with the tax rates for different states, expressed in percentiles. Iterate through all states and print the value of a meal, where the pre-tax food price is $20; show the prices for tip percentages of 15%, 20%, and 25%."

```
tax = {
    "Alabama": 13.50,

    "Alaska": 7,

    "Arizona": 10.73,

    "Arkansas": 11.63,

    "California": 10,

    "Colorado": 10,

    "Connecticut": 6.35,

    "Delaware": 0,

    "District of Columbia": 5.75,

    "Florida": 7.50,

    "Georgia": 8,

    "Hawaii": 4.50,

    "Idaho": 8.50,

    "Illinois": 9.75,

    "Indiana": 7,

    "Iowa": 7,

    "Kansas": 9.65,

    "Kentucky": 6,

    "Louisiana": 11,

    "Maine": 5.50,

    "Maryland": 6,

    "Massachusetts": 6.25,

    "Michigan": 6,

    "Minnesota": 7.88,

    "Mississippi": 7.25,

    "Missouri": 9.35,

    "Montana": 0,

    "Nebraska": 7.50,

    "Nevada": 8.10,

    "New Hampshire": 0,

    "New Jersey": 7,

    "New Mexico": 8.69,

    "New York": 8.88,

    "North Carolina": 7.50,

    "North Dakota": 8,

    "Ohio": 8,

    "Oklahoma": 11,

    "Oregon": 0,

    "Pennsylvania": 8,

    "Rhode Island": 7,

    "South Carolina": 9,

    "South Dakota": 6,

    "Tennessee": 9.75,

    "Texas": 8.25,

    "Utah": 8.35,

    "Vermont": 7,

    "Virginia": 6,

    "Washington": 9.60,

    "West Virginia": 7,

    "Wisconsin": 5.60,

    "Wyoming": 6,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better if you solve this question yourself, you will learn more from it.

A hint I could give you is this code which iterates over each key in the dictionary you are given, and prints the tax in that state.

```
for name_of_key in tax:
  print("Tax in state %s: %f" % (name_of_key, tax[name_of_key]))
```

Comment: I know how to print the statements with the words added in, example, "Tax in state Alaska: 7.0" but I don't know how to take each tax rate and insert into my function?

Comment: Use the total_cost(price,tax,tip) function. 

I.e. total_cost(20.0, tax[name_of_key], 15.0)

Comment: That's what I'm thinking, but where do I include it?

Comment: Do I include the formula in the huge tax {} list for each state?

Comment: No, do it like this:    cost = total_cost(20, tax[name_of_key], tip/100.)